# Check if new record was created in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form for a `User` model that `accepts_nested_attributes` on a `has_many` association to `Comment`.

Whenever the form is updated, I need to be able to check whether a `Comment` was added/created along with it.

Aside from checking what's inside the submitted `params`, is there a more Rails way of doing this?

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
  ...
end
```

View

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :comments do |fc|
    = fc.input :content
    ...
  end
end
```

And finally in my controller

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])    
  if @user.update_attributes(permitted_params)
    # Check if a new comment was added here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])    
  if @user.update_attributes(permitted_params)
    if @user.comments.any?(&:id_changed?)
      # do_something
    end
  end
end
```

This code exploits [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) methods

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this didn't work as once the record is saved after the `update_attributes` call, any of the `changed?` methods will return false again.